# Mysql import error - #1005 - Can't create table , (errno: 140 "Wrong create options")

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to transfer a site from one server to another, and am having trouble importing the database to the new server via phpmyadmin. When I import, I get the following error:

Error
SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `prycisio_ctfadata`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `ctf_audit`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ctf_audit` (

`id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`tableused` VARCHAR( 45 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`idref` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_user` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_browser` TEXT,
`entry_ip` VARCHAR( 16 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_session` TEXT,
`altid` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_data` TEXT COMMENT 'other user data',
`checkhidden` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`entry_type` VARCHAR( 45 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT =519;



MySQL said: [​IMG]

#1005 - Can't create table `prycisio_ctfadata`.`ctf_audit` (errno: 140 "Wrong create options")
```

I'm afraid I don't really know what I am looking at here. Can anyone help me with a solution?

Thanks

Comment: in sqlfiddle the statement works fine. Which mysql version do you use?

Comment: Thanks @Jens My server is 10.1.18-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

Answer (score 8):

Just had the same problem today and found this post here. For me the solution was to change my my.ini file. I had the following line in it, but it was quoted out:

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda # For dynamic and compressed InnoDB tables
```

Without this, my old xampp installation assumed an older version of InnoDB, which couldn't handle the ROW_FORMAT. Just add it and it should work.

Alternatively, you might just remove ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC from your import script.

Comment: Removing the `ROW_FORMAT=<format>` worked, thanks!  Can do this with `sed -i.orig 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED //g' database.sql`, just make sure it will only match the lines you want by first searching the file.

Answer (score 7):

Try to disable innodb strict mode and import again:

```
set global innodb_strict_mode=OFF;
```